# Write nested IF AND statement with 3 conditions

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help writing a nested IF statement.  Here are my conditions:

```
1st condition - if A1 is blank and G1 is blank, return a blank value; 
2nd condition - if A1>0 and G1 is blank, return value for E1-A1; 
Last - if A1>0 and G1>0, return G1-A
```

I just can't seem to write the correct IF AND statement.

Comment: Please post your latest failing attempt at solving this.

Comment: what if G1>0 and A1 is blank?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=IF(A1+G1=0,"",IF(G1="",E1,G1)-A1)
```

[image]